# Filter a text file into a new text file

Tags: windows, filtering, text-files

Sorry about the dummy question here.

Under Windows I would like to be able to filter one .txt file into a new one. Filtering all lines that contain a specific string.

I know this could well be a really easy one, but would really appreciate a few pointers please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `findstr` command:

```
findstr my-string filename > new-file
```

`findstr /?` will give you a usage message telling you how to use `findstr` (including the `/V` switch if you wanted to filter lines *out* rather than filtering them *in*.)

Or if you're familiar with `grep` and wishing you had it on Windows, install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Powershell has some neat [string comparison features](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_select_string.htm). You can pipe the output to a new file.

^^ There are some better links as to how to use Powershell - but I can't find them this minute. If you go the Powershell route there are lots of examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Add On  [Text Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qcz.text-power-tools&ssr=false#overview) contains a very powerful filter feature.

The one issue is the Visual Studio add-ons have a file size limit (this may be resolved by the time you read this). Visual Studio may open a large file that is not the issue, the issue is add-ons are restricted to a file size limit.

Answer (score -1):

There's a logfile filtering utility Logfilter (www.casstor.com), that can easily do this.  You can define multiple filter strings as well as use regular expressions in your filters.  I think it might be what you're looking for.