# How can I search and extract lines which contain a specific string in a large text file on Windows?

Tags: windows, filter, text-files

I have a large text file (3MB over 50,000 lines) and I would wish to perform a filter on it.

I see that it's quite possible to do on a Linux machine, but I don't know how to go about filtering it on windows.

I would like every line that includes a specified string (e.g. `cake`) to be copied into a new text file - simple as that. I just have no idea.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are comfortable with nix environments, try 'cygwin'...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter a text file into a new text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297706/filter-a-text-file-into-a-new-text-file)

Comment: This size `3MB over 50,000` may be considered "large" for interactive filtering, but it's indeed small for filtering in an automated way. See [Large file support - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use the MS-DOS `find` command with redirection. For example:

```
find "cake" yourfile.txt > output.txt
```

You'll have to execute the line in the directory where your large text file is located.

Source: 
http://ss64.com/nt/find.html

Answer (score 0):

C# with Visual Studio.

[c# search string in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856471/c-sharp-search-string-in-txt-file)

```
int counter = 0;
string current;
string[] cakeLines;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test2.txt");
while((current = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if ( current.Contains("cake") )
    {
        cakeLines[counter] = current;
        file2.WriteLine(cakeLines[counter]);
    }

   counter++;
}

file.Close();
file2.Close();
```